# Issue with many to many relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am not able to add one more player to this coach. Essentially a player can have many coaches,  and a coach can have many players under him.

I tried to do a Many to Many relationships but then I was able to add the same player to the same coach twice.

What should I do here ?

`class CoachPlayer(models.Model):
    coach = models.OneToOneField('Coach', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey('player.Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a foreign reference to `coach` in the model.

Now a player cannot have multiple coaches so `coach` and `player` should be unique together. So make them unique. The model becomes:

```
class CoachPlayer(models.Model):
    coach = models.ForeignKey('Coach', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey('player.Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ('coach', 'player')
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, that really helped me solve this issue and will help me solve a bunch of other issues too.